# How to put each Word in a varying space delimited file on a new line?

Tags: gvim

Basically I'm transposing my one record with many columns to many records in one column. A non-whitespace character begins a Word. I'm using gVim on Win7 so I need to use `CTRL-Q<CR>` as my new line character. The number of spaces between words is not constant.

My attempt: `:%s/\S/<CTRL-Q><CR>\S/g`

**Questions**

1. Why does my attempt not work?
2. How can I do this in gVim?

Convert

```
foo  1true   0false +pos -neg ++dblpos    (lefp        }rcurl
```

to

```
 foo 
 1true 
 0false 
 +pos 
 -neg 
 ++dblpos 
 (lefp 
 }rcurl
```

Comment: 1. Why not set the `fileformat` to `unix` and use `:%s/\S/\r&/g`? 2. Do you want to those leading spaces in front of each line given in the example output? 3. Your attempt will leave trailing whitespace, if used as intended. Do you want that?

Comment: @muru. Thanks for suggesting setting format to unix. After doing that, and trying your suggestion, I  get a new line after each character not each word. Yes, I'm content with leaving trailing white space. I can use a second command to clean those.

Comment: Oh, wait. You want `<CR>` line endings, so the `fileformat` would be `mac`, not `unix` - sorry about that. Ok, instead of replacing non-whitespace characters with themselves, replace whitespace characters: `:%s/\s\+/\r/g`

Comment: I just tried your second suggestion on ff=unix and that worked. Thanks.

Comment: When replacing with `\r`, Vim will pick the correct line ending for the `fileformat`, so it will always appear to work. If you wanted OSX line endings, I think you should use `ff=mac`. Check the content of the file using `od` or `hexdump` to be sure.

Comment: @muru Mac OS X is Unix-based and understands Unix line-endings. The `mac` fileformat is obsolete since the Mac OS 9 days and only kept around for backward compatibility (or, more probably, because cleaning up Vim's legacy code can be an [unrewarding experience](http://geoff.greer.fm/2015/01/15/why-neovim-is-better-than-vim/) to say the least).

Comment: @zool Thanks for the update. Never used a Mac myself. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be simpler if:

1. You set the `fileformat` to `unix`, so that Vim takes care of line endings;
2. You replace the whitespace instead of the non-whitespace characters.

Thus:

```
:set fileformat=unix
:%s/\s\+/\r/g
```

When `\r` is in the replacement of a substitute command, Vim will pick the appropriate line ending for the file format.

Your attempt would not have worked, since `\S` in the replacement is just `S`, not the character that matched.